convert a dataarray with 2d coordinates to dataarray with 1d coordinates
I am trying to reproject a data array on 2D coordinates to dataarray with 1D coordinate so that it can be easier to manipulate.
I used the following code
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define 1D latitude and longitude
lat = np.linspace(-90, 90, 100)   # 1D array for latitude
lon = np.linspace(-180, 180, 200)  # 1D array for longitude

# Create a 2D data array, but using 1D coordinates for lat and lon
data = np.random.rand(100, 200)  # Data array of size (lat, lon)

# Set up the DataArray with 1D coordinates
da = xr.DataArray(
    data.T,
    coords={"latitude":  (["y", "x"],np.meshgrid(lat, lon)[0]),
            "longitude": (["y", "x"],np.meshgrid(lat, lon)[1]),
            },
    dims=["y", "x"]
)

da = da.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)

da_reprojected = da.rio.reproject("EPSG:32633")  # UTM Zone 33N as an example


this code failed with error:
DimensionMissingCoordinateError: x missing coordinates.


to plot the da with 2D array you can use
da.plot(x='longitude',y='latitude')
plt.show()

[![data with lat/long]enter image description here]1
I plots the data with lat/long, however da.plot() does not work to plot the data with lat long, it uses dimension index instead of lat long in the axis.
